# unable to Update product collection via observer in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to update product collection (excluding some products, to be exact) through observer. 
I'm using the event `catalog_block_product_list_collection`
Observer is catching the event fine.

in observer execute method:

```
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $newCollection = $observer->getEvent()
            ->getCollection();
        $newCollection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => [1,2,13]]);
        return $this;
    }
```

but nothing happens.

I've also tried the event `catalog_product_collection_load_after` but the case is same.

How can i update this collection via observer?

**edit**: Using `addFieldToFilter` or `addIdFilter` results in "`main.CRITICAL: illegal state`" in log file system.log and no products shows up but overall page loads fine.

Comment: Please share ur observer code?

Comment: I've as mentioned above. for now i'm manually giving ids to the filter. what more code should i share?

Comment: share full code of observer class

Comment: what is $newCollection ? it does have any collection

Comment: sorry it was a typo. i edited the question.

Comment: I am also having the same issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204081/issue-in-catalog-block-product-list-collection-observer-event

Comment: Check that link is helpful to update product collection: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167936/magento-2-how-to-update-loaded-product-collection-in-productlist-block/352779#352779

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired result like this:

```
$observer->getEvent()
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => [1,13,5]]);
```

and used the event `catalog_block_product_list_collection`

Comment: I get the same error in my case...can u suggest here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133725/products-not-loading-in-categories-page

Comment: I have the same issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204081/issue-in-catalog-block-product-list-collection-observer-event But not working after using this solution

Answer (score 0):

For this case,you can use `addIdFilter(arrayofproductId,true)`. instead of `addAttributeToFilter()` at this case.

So in this case, use `addIdFilter([1,2,13],true)`.instead of `addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => [1,2,13]]);`

That second parameter of `addIdFilter()` function put the condition nin

See at product collection class  `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;`

```
 public function addIdFilter($productId, $exclude = false)
    {
        if (empty($productId)) {
            $this->_setIsLoaded(true);
            return $this;
        }
        if (is_array($productId)) {
            if (!empty($productId)) {
              //$exclude flag use for filter collection at nin condition
                if ($exclude) {
                    $condition = ['nin' => $productId];
                } else {
                    $condition = ['in' => $productId];
                }
            } else {
                $condition = '';
            }
        } else {
            if ($exclude) {
                $condition = ['neq' => $productId];
            } else {
                $condition = $productId;
            }
        }
        $this->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $condition);
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: yes I've tried that and also mentioned it in edit part that using the method generates an error in log "illegal state" and all products disappear.

Comment: Please clear the cache and try

Comment: did that, nothing happened. same issue