# Magento 2 : How to update loaded product collection in ProductList Block

Tags: magento2, product-list, filter, product-collection

I tried to update with **addAttributeToFilter()** but not working.

Here it is::

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            $layer = $this->getLayer();
            /* @var $layer \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer */
            if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
                $this->setCategoryId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
            }

            // if this is a product view page
            if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')) {
                // get collection of categories this product is associated with
                $categories = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')
                    ->getCategoryCollection()->setPage(1, 1)
                    ->load();
                // if the product is associated with any category
                if ($categories->count()) {
                    // show products from this category
                    $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
                }
            }

            $origCategory = null;
            if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
                try {
                    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($this->getCategoryId());
                } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                    $category = null;
                }

                if ($category) {
                    $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                }
            }
            $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

            $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

            if ($origCategory) {
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
            }  
        }
        $productIds=$this->getProductId($this->_productCollection);

        $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $productIds]);
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
   public function getProductId($collection)
   {
      foreach ($collection as $key => $value)
      {
         $this->product_id[]=$this->dataHelper->getRule($value->getId()) 
      // getRule() is custom method that return matched restricted product ids
      }
      $this->product_id = array_filter($this->product_id);
      return $this->product_id;
   }
```

Comment: try to print the collection and check the generated query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through collection in **getProductId** function, get all product IDs of collection as array, loop through that array and get SKU by product ID in loop as per following code

```
$this->_productCollection->->addAttributeToFilter('sku', ['nin' => $this->dataHelper->getIds($collection->getAllIds())]);
```

**Helper**

```
public function getIds($product){
    foreach ($product as $key => $value) {
        $sku[] = $this->getRule($value);
    }
    $sku = array_filter($sku);
    return $sku;
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For `entity_id` both..`addFieldToFilter` and `addAttributeToFilter` works.

```
    $productIds = array();
    $productIds[] = 1;
    $this->_productCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $productIds]);
```

I have 2 products (id=>1, id=>2) only and it properly gives result which is.... it only shows product id 2.

**Now in your code i can see that you are getting value from a function named `getProductId` which is causing the issue. Use the below code for your function.**

```
public function getProductId($collection)
   {
      $ids = array();
      foreach ($collection as $key => $value)
      {
         $ids[]=$this->dataHelper->getRule($value->getId()) 
      // getRule() is custom method that return matched restricted product ids
      }
      $this->product_id = array_filter($ids);
      return $this->product_id;
   }
```

Keep everything else same. Rest will work fine. Enjoy !!

Comment: Not working, it gives blank result

Comment: @SAGARRADADIYA print the query and show us please.

Comment: addFieldToFilter still not working ,if i use static array its working fine $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => [1,2]]);   but it not working with array object  $productIds

Comment: updated my answer. Try that.

Comment: Check the answer now.

Comment: Honestly still not working

Comment: Probably you should check the return from that `getProductId()` function. If that actually returns anything.

Comment: It return product id '1'  in array "Array ( [0] => 1 )".

Comment: Then you should see products in collection except the product id 1.

Comment: Yes, you'e right inside product collection it removed product id 1 , but way it still display in product list?

Comment: If its not in collection then it wont show in listing page also.

Comment: Honestly it still display in product list

Comment: That means if you print the collection you dont see the product id 1. But still you can see product id 1 in listing page. In that case the only possibility is that your collection result is getting overridden by some other function.

Comment: when i use static array it working fine . $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => [1,2]]); but use with array object it not working $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $productIds]);

Answer (score 0):

For overriding `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` In function `_getProductCollection`. Create observer for `catalog_block_product_list_collection` event in custom module.

Create `events.xml` in the module `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml` there is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <!-- event catalog_product_collection_load_after -->
    <event name="catalog_block_product_list_collection">
        <observer name="product_collection_available" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ProductCollectionObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

and the observer method `app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/ProductCollectionObserver.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

/**
 * ProductCollectionObserver
 */
class ProductCollectionObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Handler for load product collection event
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        // here your code.....

        /* set your filter here */
        $observer->getEvent()
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code', ['operator' => 'value']);
        /* attribute_code (custom or default both are work) */
        /* If multiselect type attribute use finset as showing below */
//            ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code', ['finset' => [$attrOptionId]]); $attrOptionId like (1,2,3)
    
       return $this;
    }
}
```

Add `addAttributeToSelect('*')` before calling `addAttributeToFilter()`

`Thank You!`