# Issue in 'catalog_block_product_list_collection' observer event

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I need to filter my front end product collection to list product according to a custom attribute value. But the product listing page is not filtering according to my condition.

The code used are:
Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_block_product_list_collection">
        <observer name="disableproduct" instance="<vendor>\<module>\Observer\Collectionloadafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Vendor/Module/Observer/Collectionloadafter.php

```
<?php

namespace <vendor>\<module>\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class Collectionloadafter implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession)
    {

        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;

    }

    /**
     * Append review summary before rendering html
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $productCollection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

        $productCollection
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_group_data', array('like' => '%1%'));

            return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function getGroupId()
    {
        $customerGroup = '';

        if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

            $customerGroup = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();

        }

        return $customerGroup;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi did you find any solution regarding this ? please share with me

Answer (score 0):

Try This!

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class RestrictCollection implements ObserverInterface
{
    const CUSTOMER_GROUP = 'product_customer_group'; // Custom Attribute

    protected $session;

    public function __construct(
        Session $session
    ) {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $productCollection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerGroupId = $this->session->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
        }
        if (isset($customerGroupId)) {
            $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter(self::CUSTOMER_GROUP, ['finset' => $customerGroupId]);
        }
        return $productCollection;
    }
}
```